# IE, url character limit and sending data to an IFRAME

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an application that needs to **pass a significant amount of data to an iframe**.

Currently we pass the data using the **query string** of the URL in the src paramater.

The problem is when the size of the URL **exceeds 4096 characters** it bombs out in IE.

**What is a way to easily pass data to an iframe larger than 4096 characters?**

**Test case:** View the following link in IE 11 (my version 11.413.15063.0 on Windows 10 Pro):

http://www.whirlwind-ecommerce.com/iframetest.php

The left iframe will be empty (fail) while the right will contain content (success). The only difference between the two is an additional "&var=val" in the src URL that exceeds the 4096 character limitation.

**Code for the above example:**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Iframe test</h1>
<iframe src="http://www.whirlwind-ecommerce.com?var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.whirlwind-ecommerce.com?var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val&var=val"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please include the code...

Comment: @Seabizkit code added